# How to read a WCP 1252 string into an std::tstring?

Tags: android, c++

I have a string in a WCP 1252 encoded header file:

```
#define MY_STR "This string has some fancy characters like ©"
```

How can I read this into a `std::tstring` using a compiler and runtime environment which likes UTF-8 (running on Android, specifically)?

`_T(MY_STR)` doesn't work.  Looping through the characters and appending them one at a time works, but is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using preprocessor #ifdef's to initialize the string depending on the platform, and each string literal was encoded according to that platform's preferred encoding.